# Can't find Raspberry_pi section (rpi gpio ) in node-red after an update

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, node-red

i used node red to control a led from a local server I had a section in nodes called "Raspberry_Pi" where i could add rpi gpio output/input  and other interesting stuff

[image: here is the section i m talking about (IMAGE)]

Howerver after upadating node red => "**update-nodejs-and-nodered**"  I couldnt find this section. 
Rpi gpio is correctly installed in my machine but the problem is i cant access it from node red The question is **How to access Rpi gpio/mouse/keyboard/..... from node red ?**
Start Up log

```html
Start Node-RED

Once Node-RED has started, point a browser at http://192.168.1.5:1880
On Pi Node-RED works better with the Firefox or Chrome browser

Use   sudo systemctl enable nodered.service  to autostart Node-RED at every boot
Use   sudo systemctl disable nodered.service to disable autostart on boot

To find more nodes and example flows - go to http://flows.nodered.org
3 May 19:29:02 - [info]

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

3 May 19:29:02 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.16.2
3 May 19:29:02 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.10.3
3 May 19:29:02 - [info] Linux 4.9.24-v7+ arm LE
3 May 19:29:03 - [info] Loading palette nodes
3 May 19:29:07 - [info] Settings file  : /root/.node-red/settings.js
3 May 19:29:07 - [info] User directory : /root/.node-red
3 May 19:29:07 - [info] Flows file     : /root/.node-red/flows_ziedpi.json
3 May 19:29:08 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
3 May 19:29:08 - [info] Starting flows
3 May 19:29:08 - [info] Started flows
```

Comment: Edit the question to include details of what exactly you did for the upgrade. Also include the start of the Node-RED startup log

Comment: i updated node red with this command "update-nodejs-and-nodered"
that s all i did and then i couldnt the Raspberry section

Comment: And the start up log? Edit the question do not try to add it as a comment

Comment: I open an [issue](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/issues/313) on node-red github.

Comment: Are the pi nodes still in "/usr/lib/node_modules/node-red/nodes/core/hardware/"?